# How to trigger the submit using confirm dialog?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way how can I trigger the submit if the confirm variable which is `value` is true? I have a two radio button that has `onclick` event on it that will show the confirm dialog for each radio button. I just wanted to trigger the submit if the user choose the "Ok" button on confirm dialog.

```
<script>

    function showApprove()
    {
        value = confirm("Approve this document?");
        if (value == true)
        {

        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    function showReject()
    {
        value = confirm("Reject this document?");
        if (value == true)
        {

        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

</script>

<form class = "form-inline" method = "post" action = "{{ url('documents/pending') }}">

        <input type="hidden" name = "id" value = "{{$list->id}}">

        <div class = "radio">
            <label><input type = "radio" onclick = "showApprove()" name = "status" value="1"> Approve</label>
        </div>

        <div class = "radio">
            <label><input type = "radio" onclick = "showReject()" name = "status" value="0"> Reject</label>
        </div>

</form>
```

Comment: get document by id and trigger submit I guess. In jquery is easier :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function showApprove()
{
    value = confirm("Approve this document?");
    if (value == true)
    {
      document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

function showReject()
{
    value = confirm("Reject this document?");
    if (value == true)
    {

        document.getElementById("myForm").submit();

    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
</script>


add id in form



<form id="myForm" class = "form-inline" method = "post"....
```

Comment: just 1 min later than you. haha